# Reverse running totals

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am struggeling with a simple reverse calculation of running totals.
I have the following table:

```
ID    -     Date     -     Value
AA1      01.12.2019       5000
```

So, that tables shows me the bookings for each article in the past.
Now I need to sum up the totals on a daily/ weekly and monthly granularity reverse.

So:
Dec = 5000
Nevember = 8000 
etc.

Does anyone know you to achive that?
The following approach is not working:

```
=CALCULATE( [Sum of Values];
    FILTER( ALLSELECTED( 'Calendar' );
        'Calendar'[Date] >= MIN( 'Calendar'[Date])) )
```

Comment: Drawing from your DAX, I assume you are using a date table? And what are you meaning by ' reverse'? It seems you just want a summation based on a period in time (daily (which is your data already), weekly and monthly)?

Comment: Thanks for your replay! Yes, I am using a data table. With reverse, I mean backward. So the calculative sum from today to the past.

Comment: Can you share some mockup data and what the calculation should result in? I am thrown off by the statement 'need to sum up the totals on weekly/monthly granuarlity" and "from today to past". If you could give some sample data and what the end result should look like, I think I can help you out :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. Here you can find some example data with the end result: https://gofile.io/?c=IJ0DLe

Answer (score 0):

If your first data value is in, for example Row `C3`, then something like:

```
D3: =SUM(INDEX($C:$C,ROW(),1):INDEX($C:$C,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($C:$C)>0),ROW($C:$C)),1))
```

and fill down to the last row of data.

The formula will calculate more quickly if you adjust your references to only use the needed number of rows.

For example, if we create a table (`Table1`) and use structured references, something like the following:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1,ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers]),3):INDEX(Table1,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN([Value])>0),ROW([Value])-ROW(Table1[#Headers])),3))
```

or

```
=SUM(INDEX([Value],ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])):INDEX([Value],LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN([Value])>0),ROW([Value])-ROW(Table1[#Headers]))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your approach! But I am looking for a measure as you can see above. Could you translate your approach into a measure?

Comment: @joshua I did not realize you were restricting your solution to measures. You'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable than I for that.